# documento html não reconhece a folha de estilo CSS3

Tags: css3

Oi, gente,

Eu estou aprendendo html e empaquei porque meu documento não reconhece a folha de estilo do curso que eu estou seguindo. A princípio eu achei que fosse um erro no meu código, mas ele estava funcionando perfeitamente com a tag style, então percebi que o problema estava na folha de estilo, por isso eu criei um novo documento e copiei o meu código antigo para ele. E, realmente, depois disso, o documento html estava reconhecendo a minha folha de estilo, mas o código que estava nela não é o mesmo que eu tinha escrito, e o arquivo html não reconhecia nada que eu escrevia nesse novo documento.
Eu também apaguei o código que estava na folha de estilo e escrevi o meu e o documento HTML reconheceu ele até a parte que já estava funcionando com o código anterior e depois só parou de reconhecer tudo que eu escrevia, é quase como se não importasse o que eu escrevo ou apago o código fica na mesma . Isso é uma questão de configuração? Eu estou usando Visual Code, não sei se isso influência alguma coisa. Aí vai o código, ele não funciona a partir da parte /* Fomatação de imagens com legenda*/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se possível compartilhe o seu html conosco, por favor!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, utilize a tag `link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo2.css"` no seu `head` do HTML, pode ser esse o problema.